# Use a class to monitor a data stream and print reports to two different windows at different time intervals in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, stream, network-programming

I've never had much opportunity to play with threading but I need it for a project i'm working on. I've significantly simplified my problem for the example I present below, but I'm pretty sure the solution to the simpler problem will get me most of the way to solving the more complex problem.

That said, here's my reduced case: I have a class whose job it is to monitor an incoming data stream that is accessed through a class method. I am calculating statistics from the stream. I would like to print a report about the incoming data to one terminal window and short intervals, and also print a summary report to another window at regular (longer) intervals.

This demo below generates data and prints reports to the same window: how would I rework this to print the separate reports to two different windows?

```
from __future__ import division
from random import gauss
import time

class MyStreamMonitor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum   = 0
        self.count = 0
    @property
    def mu(self):
        return outv = self.sum/self.count
    def generate_values(self):
        while True:
            yield gauss(0,1)
    def monitor(self, report_interval=1):
        start1 = time.time()
        start2 = time.time()
        for x in self.generate_values():
            self.sum   += x
            self.count += 1

            # print this to terminal 1
            if time.time() - start1 > report_interval:
                start1 = time.time()
                print self.count, x 

            # print this to terminal 2
            if time.time() - start2 > 5*report_interval:
                start2 = time.time()
                print self.mu       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream = MyStreamMonitor()
    stream.monitor()
```

Comment: Could use rabbitmq or something like that and set it up as a client/server application. The monitor servers the data, the clients listen on particular channels/queues for whatever data they need.

Comment: or could use regular socket connections/gevent, open up two sockets on different ports and have the clients listen on them.

Comment: I like your general approach but have never used sockets before (without a framework like flask handling things). Could you maybe show me a minimal working example or direct me to a tutorial?

Comment: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/echoserver.py#L34 is an example of echo server using gevent.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: @reptilicus Ended up using redis pubsub to pass messages from the data stream monitor to the reporting components. If you want to reframe one of your comments as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I can write up a simplified version of what I'm doing as a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm too lazy, but you should put up an example for others who come across this question if you have time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking @reptilicus' advice and built this as a client/server application with redis. Here's a minimum working example:

**server.py**

```
from __future__ import division
from random import gauss
import time
import redis

class MyStreamMonitor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum   = 0
        self.count = 0
        self.r = redis.StrictRedis()
    @property
    def mu(self):
        if self.count >1:
            outv = self.sum/self.count
        else:
            outv = 0
        return outv
    def generate_values(self):
        while True:
            yield gauss(0,1)
    def monitor(self):
        for x in self.generate_values():
            self.sum   += x
            self.count += 1

            # This is the magic here
            self.r.publish('count', self.count)
            self.r.publish('mu', self.mu)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream = MyStreamMonitor()
    stream.monitor()
```

**listener.py**

```
import redis
import time
import sys

r = redis.StrictRedis()
channel = sys.argv[1]
interval = float(sys.argv[2])

while True:
    # Resubscribe at each iteration to ensure we are only receiving
    # the newest message
    pubsub = r.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe(channel)

    _ = pubsub.listen().next() # the first message is always just a "1"
    message = pubsub.listen().next()

    print message['data']
    time.sleep(interval )
```

The server publishes data to the "count" and "mu" channels. So to run this, first we need to open up a terminal and kick off the server:

```
$ python server.py
```

Then we can open up a separate terminal for each channel we want to listen on, passing in the channel we want to listen to and the sleep interval as arguments.

First terminal:

```
$ python listener.py mu 1
```

Second terminal:

```
$ python listener.py count 2
```

For the record: installing redis was extremely painless and didn't really require any configuration at all. Depending on your needs installation/configuration may be more complex, but at least for this toy example I didn't need to do anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to write to a text file, and then in second terminal, just tail the file:

```
def monitor(self, report_interval=1):
    second = open('report.txt', 'wt')
    start1 = time.time()
    start2 = time.time()
    for x in self.generate_values():
        self.sum   += x
        self.count += 1

        # print this to terminal 1
        if time.time() - start1 > report_interval:
            start1 = time.time()
            print self.count, x 
            second.write('%d, %s\n' % (self.count, x))

        # print this to terminal 2
        if time.time() - start2 > 5*report_interval:
            start2 = time.time()
            print self.mu
            second.write('%s\n', self.mu)       

        second.flush()
```

Then on the second terminal:

```
$ tail -f report.txt
```

Comment: I guess that works, but it feels very hacky. Also, I'd have to truncate the file before each write.